# How to configure Nginx Load Balancer for WSO2 IS + EI + BPS cluster on the same server?

Tags: wso2

I have one server with WSO2 IS,EI,BPS and 2nd server with IS,EI,BPS. I want to create a cluster with Load Balancer. IS uses 9444 port, EI uses 9443 port, BPS uses 9445 port. I can't configure correctly Nginx for Load Balancing for 3 systems, because all systems use different ports. I didn't find any info in documentation. Where should i write different ports of IS,EI,BPS in Nginx config to open LB web-page with different ports for IS,EI,BPS?

I configured Nginx LB for IS cluster, it works. Then i configured Nginx LB for EI, it works. Then BPS. I don't know how to merge these configurations in 1 config.

Config for EI. Configs for IS & BPS the same but with other ports.

```
upstream example.com (SHOULD I WRITE 9443 PORT HERE?) {
    server 1.1.1.1:9443;
    server 1.1.1.2:9443;
    ip_hash;}
server {
    listen 443 (SHOULD I WRITE 9443 PORT HERE?);
    server_name example.com (SHOULD I WRITE 9443 PORT HERE?);
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
        proxy_pass https://example.com (SHOULD I WRITE 9443 PORT HERE?);
        proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.cer;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 3 hostnames for the servers as below.

- bps.wso2.com
- is.wso2.com
- ei.wso2.com

Then you can define 3 upstreams and 3 servers. Example config can be found in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+the+Proxy+Server+and+the+Load+Balancer

Comment: ok, thx. So there is no way to do it with ports after name of server, like example.com:9443, yes?

Comment: You can do with ports as well. change the port 443 to 9443

Comment: I tried to do it with ports. I changed port 443 on 9443, but after that i receive errors on nginx: Too many open files and worker_connections are not enough. I increased needed values to solve these errors, but still get errors.